# API do find out if trash works on a given network volume

Tags: macos, recycle-bin

For some network volumes OSX does not support the trash concept. When you attempt to delete files on such a volume you get a warning dialog telling you that files will be deleted forever.

Is there an API to check whether this is the case before doing the actual deletion?